# How to get all content (text and images uploaded) of a post , posted by a page?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get all text and images posted in a post by a page.

Currently I got something like

https://graph.facebook.com/{page ID}/posts?&access_token={access token}.

In response , I am getting list of posts , But in each post  only one picture link in coming while there are multiple images uploaded to that post . How to get all images that uploaded in a post?

Response :

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1c-pkorfy-ib4CjRhMEl3SME1WkyZ6DP8hLiJR96AfS0/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you call https://graph.facebook.com/{page ID}/posts?&access_token={access token}, you can get the **id**. So, use this id as **post_id**. Assume the post_id is 555361861181187_706802686037103, so you can do FQL query:

> SELECT attachment, created_time FROM stream WHERE
>   post_id='555361861181187_706802686037103'

Screenshot:

[image]

As a alternative way, you can just use FQL instead of graph.facebook.com/{page ID}/posts endpoint. Assume 555361861181187 is page ID, e.g.

> SELECT attachment, message, created_time FROM stream WHERE
>   source_id='555361861181187' AND created_time<=now() ORDER BY
>   created_time DESC LIMIT 200

Screenshot:

[image]

FQL documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Finally, please reset your **App Secret** at https://developers.facebook.com/x/apps/{APP_ID}/dashboard/